# Flutter Maps: How to change Marker Icon on marker tap

Tags: google-maps, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to find a solution for changing the marker icon when the marker is tapped, in order to give visual feedback. Still, I haven't figured out how to do this. The first thought was accessing the marker by index but since markers are arranged in a `Set<Markers>` there is no change to access it in a proper way. then it would be easy to just exchange the old marker by the new one. Is there a common way to do this?

**Edit:**

Using Java, there are options like. `setIcon` for markers. This is not the chase for Flutter.

like so:

```
marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_selected_user_mark_icon));
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: you have to build a new `GoogleMap` and pass your markers in [markers](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter/latest/google_maps_flutter/GoogleMap/markers.html) property

Comment: Hey, thanks for ur answer. That's definitely away but I don't wanna rerender the whole map as it looks quite bad.

Comment: @Flacon ,  did you happen to find a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Google Maps API doesn't have this option. I resolved it manually.

You can create a flag and change the icon Marker in the Marker's onTap and GoogleMap's onTap properties.

```
int markerFlag = null;
List<Marker> _allMarkers = [];
```

**Marker's onTap:**

```
onTap: () {
            if (markerFlag != idMarker) {                  
              setState(() {
                if (markerFlag != null) {
                  _allMarkers[markerFlag] = _allMarkers[markerFlag].copyWith(iconParam: defaultMarkerIcon);
                }
               _allMarkers[idMarker] = _allMarkers[idMarker].copyWith(iconParam: selectedMarkerIcon);
               markerFlag = idMarker;
              });                
            }
          }
```

**GoogleMap's onTap:**

```
onTap: (value){
    if (markerFlag != null) {
      setState(() {
        _allMarkers[markerFlag] = _allMarkers[markerFlag].copyWith(iconParam: defaultMarkerIcon);
        markerFlag = null;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is a great solution. Just as a reminder, the markers need to be as a SET, not a LIST, so I used `markers: _markers.toSet(),` in my  GoogleMap widget. 
Does this solution have any cost of performance?

Comment: @J.Diaz is there a reference to full code by any chance? I am looking for this solution, but not getting it quite right.   are the initial markers were set as part of initState?

Comment: @just10minutes Try this, declare `List<Marker> _markers = [];`, so it is empty when initiates. Then create a separate function like `void _onMapCreated(){}`, inside you can do a loop to populate the list like this: `markers.add(
  Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId(idMarker.toString()),
    position: LatLng(lat, lng),
    icon: markerIcon,
    onTap: () {},
  )
)`
and then call the function and markers in your maps widget like this `GoogleMap(
  ...
  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
  markers: _markers.toSet(),
)` This worked great together with the above implementation of `onTap`.

Comment: @J.Diaz thank you for your response. What is idMarker here? Is it index of each marker? for eg: I have for loop to generate my markers so do I use it's index as idMarker?

Comment: @J.Diaz I feel I got this almost, but my icons are based on status, for eg: Alert will be red icon rest green. so it keeps the latest clicked status icon and passes on to the previously clicked icon. I have detailed here, if you can check and see if I can manage this that will be helpful.   https://github.com/rajesh-h/seek_assistance/issues/1

Comment: @J.Diaz it's fine I was able to resolve this. now currently it is working as I am expecting. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
//onTap Marker: 

 widget.markersStation.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(markerId),
        position: latLng,
        icon: iconMarkerStationGrey,
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            for (var j = 0; j < widget.markersStation.length; j++) {
              widget.markersStation[j] = widget.markersStation[j]
                  .copyWith(iconParam: iconMarkerStationGrey);
            }

            if (idMarkerSelected != int.parse(markerId)) {
              widget.markersStation[int.parse(markerId)] = widget
                  .markersStation[int.parse(markerId)]
                  .copyWith(iconParam: iconMarkerStationSelected);

              idMarkerSelected = int.parse(markerId);
            }
          });
   ),)


//onTap Map :

                markers: widget.markersStation.toSet(),
                onTap: (position) async {
                  _customInfoWindowController.hideInfoWindow!();

                  BitmapDescriptor iconMarkerStationGrey =
                      await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
                          const ImageConfiguration(size: Size(24, 24)),
                          "icons/marker_station_gris_17677@2x.png");

                  if (idMarkerSelected > -1) {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.markersStation[idMarkerSelected] = widget
                          .markersStation[idMarkerSelected]
                          .copyWith(iconParam: iconMarkerStationGrey);
                      idMarkerSelected = -1;
                    });
                  }
                },
```